# CQ5: links/paths in properties aren't updated on page rollout

Tags: aem, blueprint, rollout

When I create a live copy of a blueprint website, and rollout pages using standard rollout config, links in the pages are updated to reflect the live copy version.

ex. /content/myblueprintwebsite/home.html -> /content/mylivecopywebsite/home.html

But when those paths are buried inside properties of the page content nodes, they are not updated, and still points to the blueprint pages.

... is this the intended behavior? If so I guess I would have to write my own rollout config? Or is there another solution to this problem?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please add some more details to help others to understand the problem

Comment: any updates from this?

Answer (score 1):

**As per:** https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/sites/msm/msm-livecopy.html

"
When the blueprint source contains links and references that target a paragraph in a different chapter, the targets are not updated in the live copy pages. For example, a live copy is created from the Geometrixx Demo Site blueprint. Links in the Toolbar chapter that target the Services chapter are not updated in the live copy, and continue to target the original pages in the Geometrixx Demo Site.
"

**My interpretation of the above:**
- If the link to the target is created on a page that is in the ancestral line, the change will reflect in live copies.

I tested this by configuring a link to bp/en/parent/child-page on the bp/en/parent page and also on the bp/en page. 
In both cases, the corresponding live-copy/... pages reflect changed paths to the live copy specific child page.

Moreover, the change is happening for links no matter what widget is used - OotB List, a customized link widget, or hyperlink configured in the text widget.

**Further question:**
Editors may want to create links from pages that is not in the ancestor line. What then? Is there a configuration that can be set to allow the change to happen ? Or are we required to write custom rollout action?

Answer (score -1):

When ever a page rollout is done it updates all the individual content references for ex:

1. paths in property nodes, if it is stored individually i.e., not concatenated  with any other text like: hello /content/test/master/en.

   It doesnt update if the path is in the mid of other text.

And

- Creating custom roll out doesn't server your purpose.If u really want to create custom roll out to meet this requirement then you have to create following custom live actions and write logic to find paths and then modify them.
  1.ContentCopyActionFactoryCustom
  2.ContentDeleteActionFactoryCustom
  3.ContentUpdateActionFactoryCustom
- Creating custom roll out is a risky option as roll out is called from many places like while creating live copy,from blue print section , roll outing a page and its sub pages and background execution etc.,We have to handle any exception caused in this explicitly.If u start changing one file then u end up changing all related files has roll out implementation on many java classes.
- Ideal Solution : Save all the paths in a individual property and AEM will take care of updating there references

Cheers !!

Comment: Hi Dilip, do you have a link to a document from Adobe/Day explaining that "problem"? Didn't find anything using Google...